# Why can't I delete a file with a Bash script?

Tags: bash-scripting

I can't seem to run `rm` from a Bash script and remove a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf myjunk.out
exit 0;
```

doesn't remove `myjunk.out`.

Comment: Get rid of the `exit 0` and check for error messages.

Comment: And it DOES work when you just execute `rm -rf myjunk.out` from the command line? What is triggering execution of this script?

Comment: Just for the record, -r is meant to descend on directories (Recursive), so if you intend to remove a file, -r is futile. What error do you get ? How do you run this script ? What are the permissions on this script ?

Comment: @BloodPhilla  it's triggered because myjunk.out is generated earlier in the script.... @Torian  -r was in there because I was just trying stuff out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure that you can delete *myjunk.out* without running your script; if not, check file attribute with `lsattr`.

Second, You don't need to providing `exit 0;`

Later, point a path to *myjunk.out*, such as:

```
rm -rf /path/to/myjunk.out
```

Comment: Also remove the `-r` flag. it is unnecessary and dangerous.

Comment: Actually, taking out the exit 0; allowed rm installed.out to execute properly.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the explanation of : Why the "exit 0" will make the rm not working

Answer (score 0):

The `-f` option inhibits error messages.  The man page says:

> Attempt to remove the files without prompting for confirmation, regardless of the file's
>                    permissions.  If the file does not exist, **do not display a diagnostic message or modify
>                    the exit status to reflect an error.**  The `-f` option overrides any previous `-i` options.

I've emphasised the part that is relevant; to get worthwhile warnings, you should remove the option flags from your `rm` command:

```
rm myjunk.out
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.